# puppet manifest example start with string condition

Tags: puppet

I am struggling to find the answer something like using "case" statement or "if-else" statement in puppet manifest. For example ..this below is a pseudo step.

```
jdk_version=1.8

if $jdk_version starts with 1.8
  then... 
elsif $jdk_version starts with 11.0.15
  then ... 
fi
```

This above psuedo step, how do we achieve in puppet manifest in order to use regex and find matching string. Pardon, i have been googling a lot and  assuming if this is below example valid to set in puppet manifest per this stackoverflow link - [Function in puppet for checking if a string contains another string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19283190/function-in-puppet-for-checking-if-a-string-contains-another-string)

```
if $jdk_version =~ /^1.8\.\d+\_/ {
  notice("this is java version starting with 1.8.0_201_snc1_b09-1.x86_64 $jdk_version")
}
```

and

```
if $jdk_version =~ /^11\.\d+\.\d+/ {
  notice("this is java version starting with 11.0.15b10_snc1-1.x86_64 $jdk_version")
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to do branching conditionals in Puppet: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/lang_conditional.html?

Answer (score 0):

Solution already answered replied by Matt Schuchard.
https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/lang_conditional.html